# recompiling php for osx with IMAP support

Tags: php, macos, imap, recompile

Yesterday I spent quite some time trying to recompile PHP for OS X. I tried several guides I found on Google but they all seemed outdated.

Is there anyone who knows how to recompile PHP on OS X? I want to do this so I can make a CakePHP web application that reads information from IMAP. I would love to use [this](https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-emails-plugin) CakePHP plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as CakePHP itself dosen't need to get recompile with php you can use [Macports](http://www.macports.org/)

To install imap you can use:

```
su port install php5-imap
```

macports offers a lot of "ports" (library) for php and as long as CakePHP dosen't use something uncommon it should work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply, I tried this but I got the following error:


→ sudo port install php-imap
Password: ****
Error: Port php-imap not found
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>

Comment: sorry my bad use: su port install php5-imap  :)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! Now I bump into another problem, it seems my build in Apache doesn't use this newly compiled php version.. Anyone knows how to change this?